# Logging clicks on a particular link

Tags: facebook, logging

I have a link on my facebook page and I want to generate a log that records which user clicked that link at what time. How can I do this ?

Comment: Is this a link on your facebook page to a landing page outside of facebook that you have control over?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. But you might be able to get some statistics with [Facebook insights](https://www.facebook.com/help/390967410974308/?q=insights&sid=08DUv4TNC0xs8xkCq).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see which user clicked that link and at what time. That would be a violation of privacy. Facebook Insights are aggregated analytics.

The most you can so it use a link-tracking service such as bit.ly. But that won't tell you anything more than Facebook Insights will.